# Sending EPPLus Excel file via HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, epplus, httpcontext

I'm using the EPPLus library for my .NET Core 3.1 app; at the moment I'm trying to implement a simple `Export` function that makes a sheet based on the given data and instantly downloads it to the users PC.

I've got the following:

```
    public void Export(ProductionLine productionLine, HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "This is cell A1";


            context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            context.Response.Headers.Add(
                          "content-disposition",
                          string.Format("attachment;  filename={0}", "MySheet.xlsx"));
            context.Response.SendFileAsync(package);

        }
    }
```

The `HttpContext` is given via a controller that simply calls the HttpContext controller base. The HttpContext is based on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`

The current error I've got is `cannot convert from 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileInfo'` logical, but changing the file to `IFileInfo` isn't something that's possible I believe.

Is there another way of sending the EPPlus file via a HttpContextResponse?

Comment: Why are you writing to HttpContetxt.Response instead of returning an ActionResult, eg using `return File()` ? As for what's wrong, the error is *very clear*. You tried to use a type with a method that expects a completely different tone

Comment: I wasn't familliar with return File() and I wanted to use the context so I could instantly download the file to the client's pc. I do understand my error now, cheers though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around, it seems that it's easier to use the `return File()` function. I've redone my `Export` function like so:

```
    public object Export(ProductionLine productionLine, HttpContext context)
    {

        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

        FileInfo fileName = new FileInfo("ExcellData.xlsx");
            using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(fileName))
            {
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "This is cell A1";

            MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
            result.Position = 0; 
            
            package.SaveAs(result);

            return result;
    }
```

And my Controller like this:

```
    public IActionResult ExportCSV([FromQuery] string Orderno)
    {
        try
        {
            ProductionLine prodLine = _Prodline_Service.GetAllByOrderno(Orderno);
            MemoryStream result = (MemoryStream)_ExcelExportService.Export(prodLine, HttpContext);
            // Set memorystream position; if we don't it'll fail
            result.Position = 0;

            return File(result, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are several duplicate questions that show just that. Besides, all Controller actions are expected to return an IActionResult. Why try to write to the Response directly?

Comment: What do you mean with `write to the Response directly?`